# How to search math equations in a PDF?

Tags: calculus

I have a bunch of equations that I need to search and find in a PDF document. Do you know a way to achieve this?

Using CTRL+F doesn't allow searching in LaTeX format, like,

```
\frac{1}{2}
```

Searching this in search bar isn't working.

Any ideas would be awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122013/search-for-latex-in-pdf for help! In a standard manner, you would have to simply find the UNICODE characters. If it is a fraction try copying with "Copy with formatting" in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Should I write it as a possible answer for the post? What is not proven is if "Copy with formatting" helps with the problem, I am not able to prove it because I don't have a Pro license active.

Comment: I have found other articles regarding this issue. Check: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86572/copying-latex-from-a-pdf and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex.

Comment: It should be targeted to StackOverflow or SuperUser or ETC